# Error in chromedriver directory path with ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Using Ruby selenium-webdriver 3.142.6

My tests work, but at the start of the run it displays the message

```
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/w
ebdriver/common/platform.rb:136:in `assert_file': not a file: "C:\\\\Program Fil
es (x86)\\\\ChromeWebdriver" (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/l
ib/selenium/webdriver/common/platform.rb:140:in `assert_executable'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/l
ib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.rb:38:in `driver_path='
        from Prueba_Selenium_Ruby.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

Searching the web for articles related to the warning has references to Capybara, RoR, and chromedriver-help, none of which I’m using.The other problem is that all Selenium Tutorial with Ruby are outdated
Here is the code

```
require "rubygems"
require "selenium-webdriver"

Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Service.driver_path = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ChromeWebdriver"

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome

driver.navigate.to ("http://google.com/")
driver.close
```

My system
Windows 8.1
Ruby 3.0.0
P.S:"C:\Program Files (x86)\ChromeWebdriver" use this syntax or it doesnt even reconize the path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got what is your problem.

When I write

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Service.driver_path = "C:\\Ruby27\\bin\\chromedriver"
```

Your error is thrown.

But when I write

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Service.driver_path = "C:\\Ruby27\\bin\\chromedriver.exe"
```

It works perfectly.

The difference is, when you give `chromedriver`, it's not working. When you give `chromedriver.exe` it works fine. Try it now.

Comment: yes, i reviewd my code and it was missing a R in chromedriver.exe, thank for your answerd, it worked perfectly